# iPhone: my Video Recorder API code doesn't work

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to implement Video recording functionality for my iPhone 3.0 and iPhone 3.1.2 device as well. I created a sample app for that and kept a button called "Start Video" in a UIView. Then i call the below function code when click Start Video button clicked.

```
-(IBAction) StartVideo
{

 UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

 imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;

//imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
 imagePickerController.mediaTypes =  [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;

 [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];

 [imagePickerController release];

}
```

UPDATE: When i check the below code snippet to find video is supported or not, it returns me as Video not support alert as mentioned below. I don't understand what is wrong here?

```
NSArray *media = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
                      UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    if([media containsObject:(id)kUTTypeMovie]) 
    {
        imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray
                                    arrayWithObjects:(id)kUTTypeMovie,nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Video not supported");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Nothing"
                                                        message:@"Video not supported"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];        
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
```

I tested this code on 3.0 2G and 3.1.2 3G as well, but it is crashing when i click on "Start Video" and going to device home screen. I downloaded some third party free video recording app called "Record Video", it works awesome, does video recording and share files very well.
I want to know how to implement recording video on iPhone 3.0, 3.1.2 and 4.0 devices.
NOTE: I am testing on 2G and 3G devices only.

Could somenone guide me?

Thank you.

UPDATED:

I tested the code (function: StartVideo) with iPhone 3GS device and it's working as expected. I don't know why does it say as "video not supported" on 2G and 3G phone's.

Comment: Where does it crash?  If you run this in the debugger, what exact line does it halt on?  Is there any exception being logged to the console?  You need to give us a little more information to work from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you setting a delegate to handle returns by the `UIImagePickerController` ? you need to set a delegate (possibly the view controller you are presenting the picker from) that implements the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol

Comment: See line 11: `imagePickerController.delegate = self;`

Comment: yea, but it looks like copy/paste code...and you need to set self as  a UIImagePickerControllerDelegate. thats all i meant.

Comment: It is already there right as imagePickerController.delegate = self; ??

Comment: I know the crash is happening at "imagePickerController.mediaTypes =  [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];" . I tested with 3.0 and 3.1.2 devices as well, both are giving the same result.

Comment: I tested the code (function: StartVideo) with iPhone 3GS device and it's working as expected. I don't know why does it say as "video not supported" on 2G and 3G phone's.

Comment: Do you mean hardware support of video recorder is not there on those phones? Then how come a third party app called "Record Video Free" developed which works fine on those phones?

Comment: The 3g and 2 don't have built in video support on their camera (hardware), the apps that allow it do something with monitoring the camera's view and recording each frame i believe, or atleast don't use the built in functions to deal with video like you are (because they werent around when these apps came out when iphone 2 and 3g were the maximum hardware).